# How do you disable auto-closing single quotations inside strings?

Tags: string, visual-studio-code, auto-close

I like the functionality of autoclosing brackets, quotations, etc...  but when you're inside a string for instance: "`<inside here>`" and you start typing a single quote or if the quotes are inverted it'll try to auto pair quotations inside the string. Is there a way to disable this functionality inside strings?

Comment: There is no separate switch for selectively disabling quotation matching, only a global setting for all.

Comment: I've answered to this question on other place. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253814/how-to-turn-off-double-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio-2019-for-c-edit/58975154#58975154

Answer (score 7):

```
// Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
```

In your `settings.json` file will disable auto-closing brackets, parentheses, quotes, etc.

There is no separate switch for selectively disabling quotation matching, only a global setting for all.

Comment: That disables it completely, I just want to disable the functionality inside strings.

Comment: There is no VS Code feature specifically for quotation marks. What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 5):

There is a setting to disable auto-closing of *all* quotes in the latest version of VSCode as of August 2018 in [VSCode 1.27](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_auto-closing-surrounding-characters). Add this to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"
```

If you want to disable this for a specific language, nest the above setting under a language-specific setting. For example, to exclusively disable this for the `scheme` language,

```
"[scheme]": {
  "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
},
```

Unfortunately, I do not think there is an option to exclusively disable auto-closing of single quotes or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try (Ctrl + Shift) while marker is in the string or something like that.

Comment: This is a vscode question - does your solution work for vscode?

Comment: I'm using vs 2019 community. I had the same problem but with c#. Looked for advise in the net but found answer accidentally. I've done many test and with me works for double and single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I used Prettier to organized my code. when used single quote it will automatic become double quote. you can use this setting.

file>preference>setting type *prettier : single quote*

tick the radio button (if true, will use single instead of double quotes)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing the settings within the VSC settings UI and it wouldn't change it. I had to edit the `settings.json` file and add a line. The `settings.json` file is located in: `C:\Users\<Your_User>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` and add this line: `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,`