# How to turn off double quotes auto-completion in Visual Studio 2019 for C++ editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

After updating to version 16.1 of Visual Studio 2019, the code editor for C++ completes double quotation characters. When I type one double quote " it automatically completes it as "".

**How to turn this feature off?** I tried to look into settings, but could not find in C++ Editors settings or All Languages settings.

**Update:** it actually only completes when I type wide string literal starting with L. For example, when I type L" it auto-completes it to L""

**Update 2:** it happens for some .cpp files but not for others. I currently do not see any pattern. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update October 2019:** it is fixed now starting from version 16.3.2. If not, then check your settings carefully.

**Short version:** This is a bug in Visual Studio, and hopefully will be fixed. You can [up-vote it here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/583332/running-code-analysys-enables-automatic-closing-qu.html).

**Longer version:**
I decided to report this bug to Visual Studio Team, but someone already did that. So if you are affected by this issue, consider up-voting it.

Link to VS bug tracker: [Brace completion when member list is up does not put the character in the right position](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/583332/running-code-analysys-enables-automatic-closing-qu.html)

Note, that while title of above bug may sound like only Code Analysis is affected, VS Team have marked another - more relevant bug as a duplicate to the above bug ([C++ automatic quote completion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/608946/c-automatic-quote-completion.html)). And it is not possible to vote closed bug, so only option is to vote the first one I mentioned.

Comment: Oh, Microsoft, seriously, I have to download 2.07 GB update just to fix a double-quote bug.

Comment: Bug is back for VS 2022 17.0.4

Answer (score 15):

Double quote auto-completion is disabled when automatic brace completion is disabled.

You can disable that in the `Tools`->`Options`->`Text Editor`->`C/C++`->`General` menu.

[image: Options menu screenshot]

As noted in one of the other answers, that option doesn't work properly in some older versions of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the original problem was caused by a bug in the VS. The bug is now fixed, and the problem is gone.

Comment: I added this answer because I found this question via search, and there wasn't an answer that told me which setting to change.

Comment: Really annoying that you can't disable the quotation mark behavior separately to the braces behavior...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS 2019 Community Verssion 16.3.9 and have found that when the marker is in the string, the (Ctrl + Shift) combination toggles automatic double-quote placement on and off.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [Kiril Dobrev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58975154/11107541), which says:

> I'm using VS 2019 Community Verssion 16.3.9 and have found that when the marker is in the string, the (Ctrl + Shift) combination toggles automatic double-quote placement on and off.

That's correct, that's where the problem lies. Ctrl+Shift or Ctrl+Space is used to switchinput methods . The issue is that the local input method has auto-completion for characters like ")", "]", "}" and more. Therefore, it's not an issue with Visual Studio at all. Simply switching back to the English input mode will resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi Wang Lao, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer looks like a comment to the answer above. Just be patient soon you'll unlock the [comment anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) privilege. Until that moment it might be worth to consider removing this answer.